# Roman Numbers - Conversion to decimal number

Tags: elementary-number-theory, education, number-systems, decimal-expansion

I have read that if a smaller number is to the left of a larger number means that the smaller number has to be subtracted from the larger number.

Ok I can understand quickly for below Roman Numbers :

```
IX = X - I = 10 - 1 = 9
```

But I have difficulty in understanding Roman Numbers that have odd Roman Numerals - say :

```
XIX
```

So if we go from Left to right we get

```
XIX = 10 + 1 + 10 = 21
```

But if we go from right to left we get

```
XIX = 10 + 10 - 1 = 19
```

So which direction we should consider before applying the rule of smaller followed by bigger Roman Numerals - left to right or right to left?

Comment: Your "right to left" should yield the same as your "left to right", as the pattern `XIX` is symmetric.

Comment: But the rule of Roman Numerals that subtract the numerals if a smaller number if followed by bigger else add - will change in my example in considering moving from left to right or right to left appraoch

Comment: When would a mathematician ever encounter Roman numbers unless they study history or archeology? I'm genuinly curious

Comment: @YuriyS: Like non-base-10 systems, it's a simple introduction to the notion that a number can have multiple representations, and that functions on numbers do not depend on the representation chosen, but algorithms _can_ use these representations. E.g. addition isn't easy with Roman Numerals, and multiplication is even harder. This gives students the insight that choosing an alternative representation can be a useful problem solving tool.

Comment: @Yuriy, it is also a way for the student to realize just how convenient the Hindu-Arabic system is, by showing that one of the popular previous systems has its set of manipulational troubles.

Comment: You can't have a smaller number to the left without having a  larger number to the right.  XIX can not mean 21 because that would leave a bigger number (X) to the right of a smaller number (I) so the I *must* belong to the one to the right and mean 9.  XIX = 19

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When reading roman numerals, I prefer to think in the following way:

Read from left to right, and if at any point the value of a character *decreases*, put a comma between the decrease.  Then, add each block together.

MCMXCVI $\mapsto$ M,CM,XC,V,I $\mapsto$ $1000+900+90+5+1=1996$

MDCCCLXXIV $\mapsto$ M,D,CCC,L,XX,IV $\mapsto$ $1000+500+300+50+20+4=1874$

MCMXCIX $\mapsto$ M,CM,XC,IX $\mapsto$ $1000+900+90+9 = 1999$

Note that 1999 was not written as IMM or MIM.  Converting from arabic numbers to roman numerals, one only uses powers of ten one apart to denote subtraction.

Comment: There is also the additional rule that multiples of 5 (V, L, D) are not used as the left "component" in a subtractive Roman numeral; i.e. nobody writes things like VX or DM.

Comment: @j.m. ya, I only explained how to convert from roman to Arabic, not vice versa

Answer (score 5):

When you are reading Roman numerals, start from the left-most character. Read rightward until the **value of the character** increases. Then, section **those two characters** off, and repeat.

That sounds really complicated, and I wrote it somewhat poorly, so here are some examples.

In $XIX$, we start with the left $X$ which is $10$. Then we move to the $I$ which is $1$. We decreased from $10$ to $1$, so we'll move on. Then we get to the right $X$ which is $10$. We increased from $1$ to $10$, so we need to section off the $IX$. It would look like this:

$$XIX = X + IX = 10 + 9 = 19$$

Here's a more complicated example:

$$MCMXXIX = M + CM + XX + IX = 1000 + 900 + 20 + 9 = 1929$$

Here we had to section off the $CM$ since we increased in value from $C$ to the second $M$. We had to section off the $IX$ since we increased in value from the $I$ to the last $X$.

One last really complicated example:

$$MMCDXLIV = MM + CD + XL + IV = 2000 + 400 + 40 + 4 = 2444$$

Answer (score 4):

You can apply the following logics:

- the units are denoted I, II, III, IV, V, VI, VII, VIII$^*$, IX; the tenths are denoted X, XX, XXX, XL, L, LX, LXX, LXXX, XC; the hundredths C, CC, CCC, CD, D, DC, DCC, DCCC, CM; the thousands, M, MM, MMM.
- numbers are written in thousands, hundredths, tenths and units from left to right.
- no other pattern is allowed.

The Roman Empire wasn't designed to last longer than until 3999 AD :)

---

$^*$Sometimes IIX is used for VIII.

Comment: There is the additional filigree of using a vinculum for numbers larger than 3999, tho.

Comment: @jm: Yep, until $\overline{3999}$.

Answer (score 3):

XIX is read left to right, the "I" is always applied to the final X.

XIX = X + IX = 10 + 9

XXI = X + XI = 10 + 11

Comment: That would mean that I take 2 Roman Numerals from RIght and move towards left until I have only one to consider.

Answer (score 0):

I have designed following algorithm to convert roman to decimal.

- Let Roman String be ......
- Replace string contents of length = 4 with appropriate content

  - *Length = 4*, Roman numerals are `VIII = 8`
- Replace string contents of length = 3 with appropriate content

  - *Length = 3*, Roman numerals are `MMM = 3000`, `XXX = 30`, `VII = 7`, `III = 3`
- Replace string contents of length = 2 with appropriate content

  - *Length = 2*, Roman numerals are `MM = 2000`, `XX = 20`, `XI = 11`, `IX = 9`, `VI = 6`, `IV = 4`, `II = 2`
- Once this is done, then follow below rules:

  - Subtract digits from each other

    - `I` can be subtracted (absolute) from `V` or `X`
    - `X` can be subtracted (absolute) from `L` or `C`
    - `C` can be subtracted (absolute) from `D` or `M`
  - Finally there will be a bunch of digits. Add all of them to get the answer

Answer (score 0):

To avoid confusion , the only pairs of Roman numerals that follow the "subtraction" rule are IV, IX, XL, XC, CD, CM. So if your shirt size followed Roman numerals ( which it does not) L would be 50, XL=50-10=40 and XXL = 10+40=50 . Therefore L would be equal to XXL size in Roman numerals !! Coming onto XIX , this equals 19 . Here we must keep in mind the other rules of Roman numerals also and not just addition subtraction. 20 as a digit as a whole is represented as XX and therefore 21 would be XXI. In XIX reading from left to right take IX as a complete digit ie 9 and therefor XIX =19